# How to define Stored Procedure outside JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have some stored procedures which select data from multiple entities, so where should i define them as they are not getting there data from a single repository?
i have defined stored procedures specific which are strictly getting data from single table in there entity classes like this

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "accounts", schema = "ma_db")
   @NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
            @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name="getAccountsList", procedureName = "GET_ACCOUNT", parameters = {
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "UserId", type = String.class)
            } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really impossible to tell without more information about you application and the SP in question. 
But here are some guidelines:

Think about what the SP is doing. What is the main domain concept it is concerned with?

This doesn't have to be an entity, maybe you don't need such an entity in your java code, maybe you need it and haven't realized it yet.

One typical example where I have seen this situation is with reports or exports. Those are domain objects as well, although they often don't match to a JPA entity.

If there really isn't a matching entity to associate the SP with, maybe the right thing to do is to just create a simple class that executes the SP using a `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Jens, Yes the data this SP is fetching is for report, and i have just created a simple class as you said which is using JDBCTemplate and it's working perfect. thanks!